# How to prevent my website links being displayed in chrome://cache?

Tags: html, google-chrome, flash, caching

chrome://cache displays all recently cached file. i want to hide my swf flash links from it. Is there any way to hide my swf flash files in chrome as well as in other browsers.

Comment: I doubt you can hide swfs in the cache as the cache is stored and displayed on the browser side. But you could prevent your page (and swf) from caching by setting the page headers to no cache: <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> . Of course, this also would lead to increased bandwidth and loading times

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Above meta tag is for html4.01 can you please give me tag for html5.